# Convert C# model to plain json-string

Tags: javascript, c#, json, razor, encoding

Is there any simple way to convert an `C#`-object into a plain string that is escaped and can be used by javascript?

I try to pass the string into a jQuery-function which will replace some parts of this string with real values to pass them as request-object via `$.ajax`.

Whatever I tried (found in the internet) doesn't work.

Currently I have:

```
var jsVariable = "@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new MyClass()))"
```

but this throws an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` as of the `"` are not escaped correctly.

**Update 1**

At the end I would like to have the JSON-string like

```
"{"Prop1": "{0}", "Prop2":"{1}"}"
```

on which I can (in `javascript`) call

```
var request = string.Format(jsVariable, value1, value2);
```

to enable

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "someUrl",
    data: $.parseJson(request),
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("success");
    },
    dataType: "JSON"
})
```

Comment: are you looking for : http://www.newtonsoft.com/json ?

Comment: I think you can use the json serializeation method that will convert to the json object

Comment: @tschmit007 : same want to say

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the double quotes.

Make sure this is added in the script tag of your view.

```
var jsVariable = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new MyClass()))
```

you'd then get a javascript object with its properties - provided `MyClass` is defined, and is accessible in your CSHTML.

`jsVariable.myProp, jsVariable.myOtherProp` . .  etc

Comment: That's what I partially also ended up with. I thought there would be a simple way to have this as string inside javascript to replace the property-values like `string.Format(jsVariable, value1, value2)` and build the `$.ajax` data from this. So it's more like some kind of a template of the `Request`-object

Comment: if you want to alter the property values and pass it to your ajax call - you could just alter your properties like this:  jsVariable.myProp = yourNewValue, then you could pass the same object to your ajax call - data: JSON.stringify(jsVariable)